# Start local PHP script w/ local Python script

Tags: php, python, os.system

The Python program I'm writing needs to start a local PHP script outside of Python's process. The program also needs to pass params to the PHP script. So far this seems to start the script:

```
os.system( path_to_script_here param param )
```

However, I'm pretty certain that Python remains running until the PHP script is complete.

I've also looked at the various os.spawn methods and I'm not sure which would be appropriate for my case. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-call-external-command-in-python/92395#92395

Comment: Thanks for the links and sorry for the duplicate. I searched for a while before posting and didn't see either of these questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: [How to start a background process in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196074/starting-a-background-process-in-python)