# Shebang to start a Python script with nohup

Tags: python, bash, shebang

I find it quite long to have to write:

```
nohup python -u myscript.py > log.txt 2>&1 &
```

each time I want to launch a Python script as a background process.

**Is it possible to have a shebang-like first line of script like:**

```
#!nohup python -u myscript.py > log.txt 2>&1 &
import time
while True:
    print 'hello'
    time.sleep(1)
```

such that a command like

```
run myscript.py
```

would automatically start the script **with the command present in the first line of `myscript.py`?**

*Note: I'm looking for a single-file solution, I don't want to have to have a second file `myscript.sh` bash script along `myscript.py` to do this job.*

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to just handle the SIGHUP signal in your Python script, as well as writing to a log file instead of to stdout/stderr?

Comment: As an alternative to use nohup, you could just fork your program to background. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975124/bring-the-current-python-program-to-background

Comment: @gurka No, I'm looking for a general solution, to be able to launch a python script with command written in the first line

Comment: @andreas-hofmann : yes but then how to log stdout to file `> log.txt 2>&1 &` ?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid, that it is not directly possible, but you can overcome it like this:

create file run_py.sh somewhere (maybe in /home/basj/bin/ ) and make it runable:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup python -u "$@" > log.txt 2>&1 &
```

then include in your python files this header (and make them runable)

```
#!/home/basj/bin/run_py.sh
print "I am in python on background with nohup now :)"
```

Comment: `/home/basj/..` you deserve an upvote for such details

Comment: Sorry but I'm really looking for a solution without a second file (see question). If I have to use 2 files, I'll just create a `myscript.sh` in the same folder, which is the simplest solution requiring 2 files.

Comment: and make function in .bashrc is also no way for you? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix) states only one parameter is possible :(

Answer (score 0):

well, this one writes to `nohup.out` instead of a custom file. And afaik, suspending to background using a shebang hack is not possible

```
#!/usr/bin/nohup python

import sys

print("to stdout")
print("to stderr",file=sys.stderr)
```

Giving arguments to shebang interpreter ([Berkeley exec hack](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2008-05/msg00053.html)) does not support any form of io redirection, so your best bet might be to use a custom script as decribed in [gilhad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34697153/1682131)

Comment: This process won't continue in background, if I log out from SSH ?

Comment: it will run in background after logout, just run with a `&` as in `./script &`

Comment: **disclaimer** : looks like this one appends to nohup.out only after the process dies out.

Comment: argh, then it seems that this solution is not usable : the process may run for weeks, so I definetely need to read nohup.out in the meantime

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above, you could try to use os.fork() to send your script to background. As for stdout/stderr redirection, you can additionally overwrite the filehandles to achieve the desired result. Look at this example:

```
import os
import sys

class LogWriter(object):
    def __init__(self, logfile):
        self._f = open(logfile, "w")

    def write(self, data):
        self._f.write(data)
        self._f.flush()

logger = LogWriter("test.log")
sys.stdout = logger
sys.stderr = logger

if os.fork():
    sys.exit()

# Main loop
import time
while True:
    print 'hello'
    time.sleep(1)
```

The class LogWriter is introduced to add a flush() to every write, which occurs. The forked process remains running, if you close the ssh session which started the script.