# Python interpreter waits for child process to die

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Contents of `check.py`:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import sys

def slp():
 time.sleep(30)
 f=open("yeah.txt","w")
 f.close()

if __name__=="__main__" :
 x=Process(target=slp)
 x.start()
 sys.exit()
```

In windows 7, from `cmd`, if I call `python check.py`, it doesn't immediately exit, but instead waits for 30 seconds.  And if I kill `cmd`, the child dies too- no `"yeah.txt"` is created.

How do I make ensure the child continues to run even if parent is killed and also that the parent doesn't wait for child process to end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module instead.

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to want is running your script as a background process. The solution in [How to start a background process in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196074/starting-a-background-process-in-python/1196122#1196122) should do, you will have to specify some command line parameter that tell your script to go into `slp` rather than spawning a new process.