# Launch an independent process with python

Tags: python, windows, process, subprocess, daemon

I have a python script and I want to launch an independent daemon process. I want to call ym python script, launch this system tray dameon, do some python magic on a database file and quit, leaving the system tray daemon running.

I have tried `os.system`, `subprocess.call`, `subprocess.Popen`, `os.execl`, but it always keeps my script alive until I close the system tray daemon.

This sounds like it should be a simple solution, but I can't get anything to work.

Comment: A search would have found the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196074/starting-a-background-process-in-python

Comment: Yeah, I found that but it doesn't work. The script just hangs for a few seconds, doesn't launch the second process and doesn't execute the rest of the script. then it dies. I don't post question without searching and trying to figure it out on my own first.

Comment: Ah, ok sorry for the harshness then. Hmm, odd I'll check something and then get back if I figure it out.

Comment: I did forget to include `os.spawn*` in the original post however. It was one of the first ones I tried  before giving up for a few hours to clear my head and get lunch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution for Windows: `os.startfile()`

Works as if you double clicked an executable and causes it to launch independently. A very handy one liner.

http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=startfile#os.startfile

Comment: This doesn't allow passing args, unfortunately.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a couple nifty `Popen` parameters to accomplish a truly detached process on Windows (thanks to greenhat for his [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13593715/461834)):

```
import subprocess

DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008
results = subprocess.Popen(['notepad.exe'],
                           close_fds=True, creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS)
print(results.pid)
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13256908/461834) for a nifty cross-platform version (make sure to add `close_fds` though as it is critical for Windows).

Comment: This works for me, and should be the accepted answer IMO.  It still allows passing args, which the accepted answer does not.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the double-fork method.

Example:

```
import os
import sys
import time

def main():
    fh = open('log', 'a')
    while True:
        fh.write('Still alive!')
        fh.flush()
        time.sleep(1)

def _fork():
    try: 
        pid = os.fork() 
        if pid > 0:
            sys.exit(0) 
    except OSError, e: 
        print >>sys.stderr, 'Unable to fork: %d (%s)' % (e.errno, e.strerror) 
        sys.exit(1)


def fork():
    _fork()

    # remove references from the main process
    os.chdir('/')
    os.setsid()
    os.umask(0)

    _fork()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fork()
    main()
```

Comment: `os.fork()` is not available on Windows.