# How to change multiple files creation date using python script?

Tags: python, macos, shell, sorting, datetime

When i was importing my photos from my ipad to my hard disk i mistakenly imported them with the creation date of that day.

So now the true date for each photo is the modified date of it. I basically use this command to `Setfile -d "$(GetFileInfo -m _FILE_PATH_)" _FILE_PATH_` to set the creation date of my photo to its modified date. But i was wondering if there is a way to put this command line in a python script where i can batch select multiple photos to preform this action.

Also, since if I open any photo the system will change its modified date, the only way that i can guess which date some photos belong to is by sorting them by name to see which date the photos before and after it belong to.

Any ideas on how I can write a script that deduces the real date of photos which have dates larger than a specific date based on the photos before and after it?

For example, you see in the screenshot that there is a photo from May 8 between two photos from October 5, so clearly it should be taken on October 5 as well.
But unfortunately sometimes the modified date of the photos before and after a photo are also wrong so I think the program has to look for the smallest date before and after the photo to deduce the real date.
[image]

**UPDATE**

I wrote this code on the python and it works fine for single files when I drag and drop them into the terminal to give the program the path. Im wondering if there is a way to do this with multiple files.

```
from subprocess import call
import os

path = input("enter filepath: ")
info = '"$(GetFileInfo -m '+ path + ')" '
command = 'Setfile -d ' + info + path
print('Setfile -d ' + info + path)
call(command, shell=True)
```

Comment: tried https://stackoverflow.com/q/56008797/10197418 ?

Comment: In its current form this is definitely too broad. Show us the code you have so far, with a [mre] of the problem you are currently unable to solve yourself.

Comment: @tripleee hi there, i update the question with my code. This only works for single files. I wanna know how I can do multiple at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not requiring interactive input is probably a crucial improvement so that you can run this on a large number of files at the same time. The way to do that in Python is with `sys.argv`.

Also, rather than `subprocess.call`, use `subprocess.check_call` (or `subprocess.check_output` to get the output) so that you can avoid invoking a shell, and check that the subprocess completed successfully. (There will be a traceback if not; if you want something more user-friendly, wrap it in `try`/`except`. Probably look for existing questions before posting another question asking for help with that.)

```py
from subprocess import check_output, check_call
from sys import argv

for path in argv[1:]:
    date = check_output(['GetFileInfo', '-m', path])
    check_call(['Setfile', '-d', date, path])
```

Use it like

```sh
python3 script.py file1.png /path/to/file2.png ../elsewhere/file3.png ...
```

(Relative paths are resolved starting from your current working directory; no path resolves to the current directory.)