# How to fix "Extensions must be .ipynb and .py or vice versa" with ipynb-py-convert?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, os.system

I am using the following code:

```
filename = r'C:/Users/Automated Analysis.ipynb'
dest = r'C:/Users/Automated Analysis.py'
os.system("ipynb-py-convert %s %s" % (filename, dest))
```

But it give me this error:

```
    raise(Exception('Extensions must be .ipynb and .py or vice versa'))
Exception: Extensions must be .ipynb and .py or vice versa
```

I am not sure how to make my code above work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have spaces for your filenames.

Your `os.system` command becomes:

```
ipynb-py-convert C:/Users/Automated Analysis.ipynb C:/Users/Automated Analysis.py
```

...and as you can see, there are now 4 inputs. Running that directly on the command line will produce the same Exception message. It is trying to convert `C:/Users/Automated` into `Analysis.ipynb`.

Just wrap the filenames in quotes:

```
os.system("ipynb-py-convert '%s' '%s'" % (filename, dest))
```

Or you can use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run):

```
import subprocess

filename = r'C:/Users/Automated Analysis.ipynb'
dest = r'C:/Users/Automated Analysis.py'
subprocess.run(['ipynb-py-convert', filename, dest])
```

See [Advantages of subprocess over os.system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44730935/2745495) and [Replacing `os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system).