# How to launch a process from Python without locking execution folder?

Tags: python

Before open this question, I was looking at [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592219/launch-a-totally-independent-process-from-python), but its answer does not work in this case.
After I start the process, I want to delete script folder, but I cannot.
My code:

```
from subprocess import Popen

DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008
CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP = 0x00000200

app = r"C:\Windows\notepad.exe"

Popen(app, creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP, close_fds=True)
```

After running the script, I want to delete script folder, and I get:

[image]

I can delete the folder only if I close the process.
Do you have any suggestion about how can I start the process without locking script folder?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to delete the folder containing the python script itself? That sounds a bit sketchy.

```
me = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
where = os.path.dirname(me)
args = ['cmd.exe', '/C', 'rd', '/S', '/Q', where]
Popen(args, creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP, close_fds=True)
```

Comment: Yes, the folder containing the script itself. In our framework, we run the Python tests from a powershell script, and last thing is to clean up (delete the folder). And that step fails, because we start a process from a Python script.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `cwd` when starting your process? I.e., `Popen(..., cwd='somewhereelse')`