# How can i let the BASH script run as process? So that even the Python script is killed the BASH script runs forever?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I need to track and launch few BASH scripts as process (if they for some reason crashed or etc). So i was trying as below: but not working

```
  def ps(self, command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash'], shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.stdin.write(command + '\n')
    process.stdout.readline()

  ps("/var/tmp/KernelbootRun.sh")
  ps("ps aux | grep processCreator.py | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9")
```

None is working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Starting a background process in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196074/starting-a-background-process-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about running it through a subshell with disown:

```
import os
def ps(self, command):
  os.system(command + " & disown")

ps("/var/tmp/KernelbootRun.sh")
ps("ps aux | grep processCreator.py | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9")
```

Note that sometimes you have to use a null input and output to keep your process active when the terminal is closed:

```
ps("</dev/null /var/tmp/KernelbootRun.sh >/dev/null 2>&1")
ps("</dev/null ps aux | grep processCreator.py | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9 >/dev/null 2>&1")
```

Or perhaps define another function:

```
def psn(self, command):
  os.system("</dev/null " + command + " >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown")

psn("/var/tmp/KernelbootRun.sh")
psn("ps aux | grep processCreator.py | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9")
```

Answer (score 0):

This works great, as stand-alone process for my movie.

p.py:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("/var/tmp/runme.sh", shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

runme.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0.0 
vlc /var/tmp/Terminator3.Movie.mp4
```

Comment: I think vlc does run independent of the terminal by default so I'm not sure if that would apply with other commands.