# Grab output from shell command which is run in the background

Tags: python, shell, ssh

I saw some useful information in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196074/starting-a-background-process-in-python) about how you can't expect to run a process in the background if you are retrieving output from it using `subprocess`. The problem is ... this is exactly what I want to do!

I have a script which drops commands to various hosts via `ssh` and I don't want to have to wait on each one to finish before starting the next. Ideally, I could have something like this:

```
for host in hostnames:
  p[host] = Popen(["ssh", mycommand], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  pout[host], perr[host] = p[host].communicate()
```

which would have (in the case where `mycommand` takes a very long time) all of the hosts running `mycommand` at the same time. As it is now, it appears that the entirety of the ssh command finishes before starting the next. This is (according to the previous post I linked) due to the fact that I am capturing output, right? Other than just `cat`ing the output to a file and reading the output later, is there a decent way to make these things happen on various hosts in parallel?

Comment: Use fabric for this: http://www.fabfile.org/

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) for this.

> Fabric is a Python (2.5-2.7) library and command-line tool for streamlining the use of SSH for application deployment or systems administration tasks.

Example file:

```
from fabric.api import run, env

def do_mycommand():
    my_command = "ls" # change to your command
    output = run(mycommand)
    print "Output of %s on %s:%s" % (mycommand, env.host_string, output)
```

Now to execute on all hosts (`host1,host2 ...` is where all hosts go):

```
fab -H host1,host2 ... do_mycommand
```

Comment: He wants parallel execution of tasks, so he'll have to either use the -P flag, or decorate the tasks with @parallel --- http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/parallel.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use [threads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) for achieving parallelism and a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue) for retrieving results in a thread-safe way:

```
import subprocess
import threading
import Queue

def run_remote_async(host, command, result_queue, identifier=None):
    if isinstance(command, str):
        command = [command]

    if identifier is None:
        identifier = "{}: '{}'".format(host, ' '.join(command))

    def worker(worker_command_list, worker_identifier):
        p = subprocess.Popen(worker_command_list,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        result_queue.put((worker_identifier, ) + p.communicate())

    t = threading.Thread(target=worker,
            args=(['ssh', host] + command, identifier),
            name=identifier)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

    return t
```

Then, a possible test case could look like this:

```
def test():
    data = [('host1', ['ls', '-la']),
            ('host2', 'whoami'),
            ('host3', ['echo', '"Foobar"'])]
    q = Queue.Queue()
    for host, command in data:
        run_remote_async(host, command, q)
    for i in range(len(data)):
        identifier, stdout, stderr = q.get()
        print identifier
        print stdout
```

`Queue.get()` is blocking, so at this point you can collect one result after another, once the task is completed.