# Passing location through 'e' parameter in midori

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, midori

I am using midori 0.4.3. When executing midori webbrowser we can pass parameters as arguments in the terminal. For example; to make browser fullscreen we can execute;

```
midori -e Fullscreen
```

A complete list of these `executable` action parameters can be found when typing `midori --help-execute`.

My question is how can i pass this?

```
midori -e Location=www.google.com
```

I tried `:` and  also, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `midori www.google.com` or, in general, passing an URL as the single argument to a `midori` invocation?

Comment: it seems working on terminal, when trying in python `subprocess.call(["midori","foo.bar"])` it doesnt run the second call  `subprocess.call(["midori","bar.foo"])` until i close the browser. any idea to overcome it?

Comment: Ehm, no `python` in your question or your tags... however... `subprocess.call` waits for the input, you don't want to wait, so please have a look at [Starting a background process in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196074/starting-a-background-process-in-python) that shows differerent possibilities for you.