# How to let method run in background

Tags: python, adb, logcat, robotframework, android-logcat

I am calling python method from robot keyword. But I do not want robot framework to wait until test is finished because I want to run that method continuously. How to continue running next test case?
e.g. I am calling start logs (python method) from robot keyword

```
def start_logs(self):
    subprocess.call('adb logcat > test.txt', shell=True)
```

After starting logs I want to run other test cases. But robot framework keeps waiting for above.

Comment: Use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196074/starting-a-background-process-in-python

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
def start_logs(self):
    subprocess.Popen(['adb', 'logcat', '>', 'test.txt'])
```

using [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) as [Colonel Thirty Two](https://stackoverflow.com/users/646619/colonel-thirty-two) mentioned in the comments.

Comment: when I run above rather than writing to file it's just printing adb logcat to console? looks like '>' is not working?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Keyword for that! [Start Process](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Start%20Process) will call any keyword but will not wait for it to return. Don't forget to add the Process library to your project.

Comment: Start Process can not be used with keywords

Comment: @maiksaray: yes. You use Start Process with a command, not a keyword.