# Achieve os.system(cmd &) behaviour with subprocess module using python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, os.system

Possibly a duplicate of [How to start a background process in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196074/how-to-start-a-background-process-in-python)

But out of many solutions, only `os.system(commandToRunInBackground &)` seems to be simple and do the trick. 
Though, according to [Replacing os.system()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system), using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module is more recommended.
So how to run background process in terms of shell (note, **&** at the end) using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module.

Comment: Since `subprocess.Popen` is non-blocking, why you would want to background a system call made using it?

Comment: As Zev says -- why do you think you need this, as opposed to the *default* behavior of your `subprocess.Popen()`-invoked command running in the background?

Comment: `subprocess.Popen` has no equivalent to the shell's `&` operator because there's no option to call `setpgid(0, 0)` in the child process to create a new group that's in the background. Without that, if the process reads from the terminal via stdin, the terminal won't stop it via `SIGTTIN` since it's still in the foreground process group.

Comment: the reason for using `os.system` is that original syntax with `&` may be specified

Comment: There's an indirect alternative. Set the `preexec_fn` parameter to a function that calls `setpgid(0, 0)`. Then you can check if it was stopped by the terminal via `pid, status = os.waitpid(proc.pid, os.WUNTRACED);` `if os.WIFSTOPPED(status): sig = os.WSTOPSIG(status)`. This will be `signal.SIGTTIN` if it was stopped to prevent reading from the terminal, or `signal.SIGTTOU` if stopped to prevent writing. Usually the terminal is configured to allow a background process to write to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern operating systems, processes *naturally* run in parallel, and having one waiting for the termination of another is the special case.  When the `&` syntax was designed in the late 60's this was different.  Then you had to mark a parallel execution.

On a shell this sticks up to today, also because it is convenient in many cases to have the shell wait for the termination of a command before allowing the next input from the user, so there still is the case without `&` waiting for the termination.

On the programming level the case with the `&` (parallel execution) is the normal case and nothing has to be done to achieve it.

The case without the `&` (waiting for termination) can be achieved by using the `wait()` system call explicitly (this is what the shell does in most cases).

For you, just use `Popen` and don't call `wait()` ;-)

Comment: It is worth mentioning that subprocess.Popen does not run the shell by default. It accepts a list: `[program, arg1, arg2]` (to see an example, call `shlex.split(cmd)`)

Comment: Right.  When OP considered using `&` they might expect a shell interpretation step for other stuff as well.

Comment: I agree with you for the way to just use `Popen`, but not on the fact that sequential execution is only a deprecated feature from the 60's. The shells use by default sequential execution precisely to allow the input of many commands at the same time (for example from a file) while allowing each command to use the results produced in the previous one.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a 'deprecated feature' from the 60s.  But the early OSes first knew sequential operation only (but already had a command line), _then_ came the parallel execution stuff.  To achieve this on the command line one had to add something (the `&`) as a marker for this.