# How to execute next line after system command in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

After executing the first exe, it would do few validation  and later I will execute the next exe.

```
os.system ("C:/Python27/python.exe")

--Few VALIDATION--


os.system ("C:\notepad.exe")
```

But while execution, I am struck with first exe, after executing os.system ("C:/Python27/python.exe), python doesn't execute the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, os.system execute your python and waits for return (closing, finishing programme). You should use **subprocess** module. Could you try following code.

```
subprocess.Popen(['C:/Python27/python.exe'], close_fds=True)
# Few Validation
subprocess.Popen(['C:\notepad.exe'], close_fds=True) # C:\ or C:/
```

with close_fds (file descriptors), program should run in detached state, so finish script shouldn't finish other spawned process.

Comment: If I use subprocess.Popen(['C:/Python27/python.exe'], close_fds=True), program runs in detached state. 
But we if I use subprocess.Popen(['C:/Python27/python.exe'], shell=False), I am getting the same result. So what's the difference close_fds=True and shell=False

Comment: You use shell true, when you want to have minimal shell enviroment (ex. you have basic path, so you can execute ls command instead of  '/usr/bin/ls'). FDS are files descriptors (input (0) output(1) error (2)). Giving close_fds=True says to python that you won't read them, so program can be run in detached state.

Comment: Well I learned most of them on website called stackoverlow.com :) && python documentation. There is plenty of similar questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196074/how-to-start-a-background-process-in-python . Have nice day :).