# How can I execute a bash command containing '&' with Popen

Tags: python, popen

I want to run `hcitool lescan --duplicates & hcidump -R` using Popen. However Popen does not seem to consider the & (the way it works in bash scripting) and gives error as "lescan: too many arguments"
Am I doing something incorrect

Comment: What language are you using? Is it neccessary for you to use `popen()`?

Comment: I am using python and I need Popen to call the that command as I am parsing the output received by running that command.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196074/how-to-start-a-background-process-in-python

Answer (score 0):

`Popen` does not interpret shell metacharacters like `&` by default. So, you need to pass `shell=True` to get it to work. Note that if you're including strings from external sources (e.g. user's files, or user input), then this can be dangerous.

See the [frequently used arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) section of the documentation for details.

Comment: I want to run the particular function invoking the subprocess command in a continuous loop. But not sure if doing this with `shell=True` is a good idea or not. What could be the other way of achieving this?

Comment: You could start them separately, and make sure the first one is executing in the background. You'll want to wait for them both to be finished before continuing.