# Run a bash command with python in background without killing it

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I'm trying to execute a bash command with python. The problem is that the program needs to run in background so I try executing the code with `&` but the subprocess module kills it.

Who can I do it?

```
def run_command(bashCommand):
    process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand, shell=True)
    output, error = process.communicate()
    return output

command = 'bettercap -iface wlx485d60575bf2 -eval "set api.rest.username bettercap; set api.rest.password bettercap; set api.rest.address 127.0.0.1; set api.rest.port 8011; net.probe on; api.rest on" &'
run_command(command)
```

[SOLVED] It only kills it when you try to get the output.

```
def run_command(bashCommand):
        process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand, shell=True)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196074/how-to-start-a-background-process-in-python

Comment: That doesn't work on python3 `AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'P_DETACH'`