# How to wait until Program starts

Tags: python, subprocess

How can one make the python script wait until some process launched with `os.system()` call is completed ? For example a code like

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('gnome-chess')
```

With this i have to wait until `gnome-chess` is not closed

What i want is just wait until `gnome-chess` is not stated

Comment: I assume you want to start `gnome-chess` in the **background**; this question already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1196122/4309792).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subprocess.Popen` for that.

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) for docs.