# How to make Python not to wait for the end of the command?

Tags: python, datetime, time, alarm, assistant

I am making a voice assistant and when I say "set alarm" program freezing and waiting for time that alarm set. So I can't talk to the assistant until alarm plays.
Here is the code

```
if 'alarm' in said:
    engine.say('Set')
    engine.runAndWait()
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    alarm_time = datetime.datetime.combine(now.date(), datetime.time(int(said)))
    time.sleep((alarm_time - now).total_seconds())
    os.system("start alarm.mp3")
```

How to ignore it or make something to the program so it won't freeze? Maybe there are other ways for setting alarm?
Help will be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start a background process in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196074/how-to-start-a-background-process-in-python)

Comment: Use the `subprocess` module, not `os.system`.

Comment: @chepner You mean this?   `os.system("start alarm.mp3")`

Comment: Yes. `p = subprocess.Popen(["start", "alarm.mp3"])` returns immediately, running the command in the background.

Comment: No, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a [thread](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html?highlight=threading#module-threading) that'll `sleep` for the specified amount of time. Sleeping threads don't block the main thread, so it'll continue executing.

```
import threading, time, os

def thread_func(seconds):
    time.sleep(seconds)
    os.system("start alarm.mp3")

threading.Thread(
    target=thread_func,
    args=((alarm_time - now).total_seconds(), ),
    daemon=True
).start()
# Do something else here
```

`os.system` *will* block the execution, but it should be fairly quick.

Comment: It says `args=((alarm_time - now).total_seconds(), ),  
NameError: name 'alarm_time' is not defined`

Comment: I should keep this? `alarm_time = datetime.datetime.combine(now.date(), datetime.time(int(said)))`

Comment: @AlexZab, of course it does - you should specify it yourself. Just copy it from your code.

Comment: Now it says `File "Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File ".py", line 124, in thread_func
    time.sleep(seconds)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sleep'`

Comment: @AlexZab, apparently, `time` is somehow a list in your code. That's why one shouldn't reuse the names of standard functions/modules to name their variables.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thank You much!

Comment: May I ask You another question? About timer

Comment: @AlexZab, yep, sure

Comment: How to open chat here?