# how to start a process in python on windows?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ipython, spyder

I am trying to start a process using the `multiprocessing.Process` example from the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class).

Here is the example code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

def info(title):
    print(title)
    print('module name:', __name__)
    print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())

def f(name):
    info('function f')
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    info('main line')
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

I would expect the console to show me the output of the function `f('bob')`, but I only get to see the output of `info('mainline')`.

So I think the process doesn't even start??

I have never before worked with multiprocessing, I bet it's a silly mistake I'm making.

I have also tried to set the start method `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')` (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.set_start_method)), as `'spawn'` seems to be the only valid one for windows.

But I only get a

```
RuntimeError: context has already been set
```

At the moment I think, I can't get the process to start.

Any Ideas how to solve this?

P.S. I am working on windows 10 in spyder 4.2.5 (maybe this something with the ipython console? Because I have heared, this is no normal python console).

But I have also tried the same example in the normal python shell, and it also only showed the output of `info('mainline')`.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but if using multiprocessing it's probably worth just using a standard console to run Python. Years ago I'd use IDLE and I think that didn't particularly like threads/processes.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196074/how-to-start-a-background-process-in-python

Comment: Your code worked for me on Windows10 with the standard CPython interpreter (v 3.8.9).

Comment: @Peter: yes, you are right, when I run the script from cmd, it works. So I guess it is really something with spyder/ipython. Thanks for the hint! :)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:** by running the script from cmd