# How to start multiple job instance in a shell script to process multiple files in a directory?

Tags: python, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

      data_dir=./all
      for file_name in "$data_dir"/*
      do
        echo "$file_name"
        python process.py "$file_name"
      done
```

For example, this script processes the files sequentially in a directory in a 'for' loop. Is it possible to start multiple process.py instances to process files concurrently? I want to do this in a shell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have another possibility for you, if still needed. It uses the `screen` command to create a new detached process with the supplied command.

Here is an example:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

data_dir=./all
for file_name in "$data_dir"/*
do
  echo "$file_name"
  screen -dm python process.py "$file_name"
done
```

Comment: Does this process files concurrently for each file, to start its own program instance?

Comment: Yes, it should be totally different processes.

Comment: Those can then be seen (while running) through `screen -li`.

Comment: This looks very simple, and I will try it!

Comment: How to add a more parameter, integer, like 10?

Comment: Adding the parameter after the command should allow the parameter to be fed to it like so: `screen -dm python process.py "$file_name" 10`.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) and [subprocess.Popen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7224186/5707560) to start new processes.

Comment: So, if I use the subprocess.open() to start a new process for each file in a list, it one process won't wait for the other to complete? I want multi python instances to process at the same time.

Comment: Could you write an answer based on the link?

Comment: Yes, all processes will work independently. You can use `communicate()` method to block the next processes until a running one will not be finished.

Comment: So I shouldn't use 'communicate()' for concurrency?

Comment: subprocess.Popen(["python process.py", "all"]), but this gives an error. 'all' is my data directory.

Answer (score 0):

With **GNU Parallel**, like this:

```
parallel python process.py {} ::: all/*
```

It will run N jobs in parallel, where N is the number of CPU cores you have, or you can specify `-j4` to run on just 4, for example.

Many, many options for:

- logging,
- splitting/chunking inputs,
- tagging/separating output,
- staggering job starts,
- massaging input parameters,
- fail and retry handling,
- distributing jobs and data to other machines
- and so on...

Try putting `[gnu-parallel]` in the StackOverflow search box.