# Open .exe on external terminal in Python

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess

I would like to run a .exe file on external terminal.
With this code I managed to run the .exe but it starts on the same terminal I call the script

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["C:/Users/Alessandro/Downloads/BOSCH-GLM/BOSCH-GLM/dist/glm50.exe"])
```

Is there a way to run it on external terminal?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using `subprocess.Popen` instead of `subprocess.call`.

Take a look at the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196074/how-to-start-a-background-process-in-python). You can ignore the `.communicate()` call.