# Is there a way to run a subprocess until a specific condition is fullfilled?

Tags: python

For example if I call ("python3 -m http.server", shell=True). Is there a way to wait until the file is served and then end the subprocess so the script can go on?

Comment: are you sure you want that? or do you want the started server to keep running in the background?

Comment: both would be a solution for my problem. i just want the script to go on after the files was served

Comment: You probably don't need to run a entire server in a separate process if you want to serve only 1 file a single time.

Comment: this answer shows how to call a process in the background https://stackoverflow.com/a/7224186/202168