# C# start python process which listens to StandardInput

Tags: python, c#, process, stdin, process.start

I'm using `Process.start()` in python to start a python script. In general this works, but I have a problem concerning the performance when starting the python script.

The process is as follows:

1. C# starts the python script using `process.start()`
2. Python loads a larger amount of data (takes a little longer)
3. C# writes something via `StandardInput`
4. Python reads the input via `sys.stdin` and performs some operations on it based on the data loaded in step 2
5. Python writes the result from step 4 to the output using `print()`
6. C# reads the output using `StandardOutput`

This is basically my C# code:

```
public void writeToStandardInput (List<string> inputList)
{
        process.Start();

        // write Input
        for (int i = 0; i < inputList.Count; i++)
        {
            dataForPython = "StdInLine:" + inputList[i];
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine(dataForPython);
        }
        process.StandardInput.FlushAsync();

        //read output
        List<string> outputList;
        string output;
        while ((output=process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
            outputList.Add(output);
}
```

and this is my python code:

```
def main():
    data_path = download_model(*path*)
    data = load_from_checkpoint(data_path)

    operationList = []

    while True:
         line = sys.stdin.readline()

         if not 'StdInLine:' in line:
             break


         operationList .append(line)

    data_output = data.doOperations(operationList)

    for element in data_output:
         print(element)

main()
```

If there is new data coming from C# using StandardInput, I currently always have to restart the entire process. The problem with this is that the Python class loads a large amount of data each time it is started. This always takes a few seconds. The data is always the same, so it would be sufficient if the data was only loaded the first time the Python script was started.
I have not yet found a solution. One possible solution would be the following:

1. C#: Put `process.start` in class constructor, so it only starts when first initializing the class
2. Python: Load the data when starting the python script and storing it into a global variable
3. C#: create a method which gets called when something needs to get written to `StandardInput` and which then calls a method of the python script
4. Python: Method which gets called after something got written to `StandardInput` reads the input using `sys.stdin` and performs operations on the input based on the global data. So I would not have to load the data every time I get something form `StandardInput`

Is this somehow possible using stdin?

Or maybe I could split it into 2 Python classes/ scripts. The class `dataLoader` which loads `data_path and data` and only gets started once (on start of the C# application) and which keeps running the entire time. And the second class `listenToStandardInput` which gets started when something needs to get written from C# to `StandardInput` and which doesn't run the entire time in the background. `listenToStandardInput` would then use `data` from `dataLoader` and perform some operations (`data.doOperations(operationList)`) based on the input from `sys.stdin`.

I've already read some posts about subprocces (e.g. [Start a background process in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196074/start-a-background-process-in-python)) but I guess that doesn't really address my problem.

Comment: Why don't you turn the python process into a "always-running" service? Then you can think about how you want to interact with it. Maybe http/rest? Maybe a MessageQueue? ...

Comment: I also thought about http/rest. But both applications are on the same server so I don't really need the communication using http. And about messageQueues I'm not 100% sure. I am not very familiar with them.

Comment: Local http communication is not _that_ bad. It also opens up the possibility to separate them out onto different machines.