# How to launch and run external script in background?

Tags: python, background-process, external-process

I tried these two methods:

```
os.system("python test.py")

subprocess.Popen("python test.py", shell=True)
```

Both approaches need to wait until test.py finishes which blocks main process. I know "nohup" can do the job. Is there a Python way to launch test.py or any other shell scripts and leave it running in background?

Suppose test.py is like this:

```
for i in range(0, 1000000):
    print i
```

Both os.system() or subprocess.Popen() will block main program until 1000000 lines of output displayed. What I want is let test.py runs silently and display main program output only. Main program may quie while test.py is still running.

Comment: No, `subprocess.Popen()` does not block. `subprocess.run()` does; so does `subprocess.Popen(...).communicate()` or `subprocess.Popen(...).wait()`; but `subprocess.Popen()` on its own is non-blocking.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`subprocess.Popen(["python", "test.py"])` [should work](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-the-os-spawn-family).

Note that the job might still die when your main script exits. In this case, try `subprocess.Popen(["nohup", "python", "test.py"])`

Comment: subprocess.Popen(["python", "test.py"]) just launches test.py and blocks main process by waiting for the output of test.py.

Comment: That should only happen if you request `stdout=PIPE` as well. Which version of Python? Can you add a `print "xxx"` after the call to Popen to check that it really blocks?

Comment: I just tested the code above and it works for me with Python 2.5.2 on Windows. Your problem must be something else.

Comment: i tried again and it worked. sorry about the mistake and thanks for your answer.

Comment: On Linux subprocess.Popen(["python", "test.py"]) blocks effectively the main process.

Comment: @user3073745: It doesn't block on any platform. Processes are, by definition, independent of each other. They might block when you connect them with pipes. In that case, the writing side of the pipe can block when the reading side doesn't do it's job.

Comment: @AaronDigulla, actually, according to my test subprocess.Popen(["python", "test.py"]) does nothing. 
If you want to execute test.py you have to add call to communicate function, and this is blocking :
subprocess.Popen(["python", "test.py"]).communicate()

Comment: @user3073745: `subprocess.Popen()` is always only the first call of a long block of code which manages the communication between the two processes. There is no "this will always work" answer in this case.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: Is there no way to simply launch script in seperate process without blocking the main process ?

Comment: There is are many way, just not a simple one. 1. You can redirect stdio of the child to /dev/null. 2. You can run it as a background process (so you're no longer the parent). 3. You can start threads to handle the IO while your main thread continues.

Comment: @AaronDigulla - How to send the input parameters if the python scripts needs them. eg: If I execute this py file. `def start_listner(unique_id, keyword, limit):  #do something`  This `subprocess.Popen(["nohup", "python", "test.py"])` works but how can I pass unique_id, keyword and limit?

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon I can't answer that in a comment. Please ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

```
os.spawnlp(os.P_NOWAIT, "path_to_test.py", "test.py")
```

Comment: it works, but is it possible to let test.py runs silently?

Comment: silently? do you mean you don't want to see the output on screen?

Comment: yes, i dont want to see the output on screen. can i be done by adding ">> /dev/null" to the code?

Comment: Unfortunately I think os.spawn*() doesn't support output redirection!

Comment: `os.spawn*` have been deprecated by the subprocess module.