# How to spawn detached background process on Linux in either bash or python

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, fork, daemon

I have a long running python script on Linux, and in some situations it needs to execute a command to stop and restart itself. So, I would like to have an external script (either in bash or python) that executes command to restart the original script. Let me elaborate.

Suppose I have original_script.py. In original_script.py I have this in an infinite loop:

```
if some_error_condition:
    somehow call external script external.sh or external.py
```

Let's suppose I can call external.sh and it contains this:

```
#!/bin/bash
command_to_restart_original_script
```

Finally, I know the command "command_to_restart_original_script". That isn't the problem. What need is the python command to "somehow call external script external.sh". I need the external script (which is a child process) to keep running as the parent process original_script.py is restarting, ie I need the child process to be detached/daemonized. How do I do this?

Comment: Probably related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python

Comment: Another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705564/python-script-as-linux-service-daemon

Comment: May I ask a naive question? Unless you want to restart it with specific parameters, you could as well run your script in a shell loop to begin with, then just `sys.exit` it. The loop would restart it right after, without even have to perform an additional fork.

Comment: Actually my original python script is a twisted program, so I can't really run it in a shell loop as you suggest. Anyway, the answer below worked, the key was the nohup parameter.

Comment: The first two suggestions in the comments above use some complicated libraries to deamonize. I don't know if they work or not, but the nohup solution below does work and is far simpler. Hopefully this will help someone else who has this same issue.

Answer (score 4):

I found lots of suggestions in various places, but the only answer that worked for me was this:
[How to launch and run external script in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605520/how-to-launch-and-run-external-script-in-background)

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["nohup", "python", "test.py"])
```

In my case I ran a script called longrun.sh so the actual command is:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["nohup", "/bin/bash", "longrun.sh"])
```

I tested this using this run.py:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["nohup", "/bin/bash", "longrun.sh"])
print "Done!"
```

and I verified (using ps -ax | grep longrun) that longrun.sh does indeed run in the background long after run.py exits.