# subprocess blocks Django view

Tags: python, django, subprocess

I have a problem calling subprocess.Popen from a view:
The view that calls subprocess.Popen is not displayed until the subprocess finishes.
The server send "200 OK" immediately, but not the content of the page.

My question is: Is this a limitation of Django's development server or am I doing it wrong?

The server does not completely hangs, as other views can be processed in the meantime.

There are already [a few questions on that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Django+subprocess) and Google gives [a few other threads](http://www.google.com/#q=django+runserver+subprocess), but I cannot find a clear answer to my question.

I believe this is not a python issue as this commands terminate immediately:

> python -c 'import subprocess; print subprocess.Popen(["/bin/sleep", "10"]).pid'

### How to reproduce

#### Create test project & app:

> cd /tmp
>   django-admin.py startproject django_test
>   cd django_test
>   ./manage.py startapp subprocess_test

#### Replace urls.py & subprocess_test/views.py with:

- urls.py:

  from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

  urlpatterns = patterns('',
       (r'^hello$', 'subprocess_test.views.hello'),
       (r'^start$', 'subprocess_test.views.start'),
  )
- subprocess_test/views.py

  from django.http import HttpResponse

  import subprocess

  def hello(request):
       return HttpResponse('Hello world!')

  def start(request):
       subprocess.Popen(["/bin/sleep", "10"])
       return HttpResponse('start done')

#### Test it:

> ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

Go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello and http://127.0.0.1:8000/start

### Test result

"start" takes 10s to load and "hello" can be loaded during that time.
For example, I get such a log:

> [01/Feb/2011 07:20:57] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 200 12
>   [01/Feb/2011 07:21:01] "GET /start HTTP/1.1" 200 10
>   [01/Feb/2011 07:21:01] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 200 12
>   [01/Feb/2011 07:21:02] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 200 12

Using wget:

> wget http://127.0.0.1:8000/start
>   --2011-02-01 14:31:11--  http://127.0.0.1:8000/start
>   Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8000... connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
>   Length: unspecified [text/html]
>   Saving to: `start'
>
> ```
> [           <=>                           ] 10          --.-K/s   in 9,5s
> ```
>
> 2011-02-01 14:31:21 (1,05 B/s) - « start » saved [10]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you don't care what the result of the system call is, so I would assume you are trying to do some sort of offline(or background) processing.

I would suggest a cleaner way of going about it rather than directly executing a program.  Use a queueing system such as [Gearman](http://gearman.org/) to queue up processing tasks and then have a separate worker that consumes items from the queue.

This has the advantage of protecting your server when large traffic spikes happen, so you don't fork off a process each time a request to that view is made.  You can consume items as slow or as fast as you decide, independent of traffic.

Traffic may not be an issue, but I personally think it is a cleaner design decision as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Yes, it is background processing. Expected traffic is low (small intranet).  I agree a queuing system would be a cleaner but the customer is not ready for it...

Comment: If you must spawn the process, then you'll need to redirect output using pipes.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546017/how-do-i-run-another-script-in-python-without-waiting-for-it-to-finish for a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem running Django with nginx+uwsgi.  Often the breaking point is the module of web-server, in my case it was **uwsgi**. Adding `<close-on-exec/>` solved this problem. From other side the **fastcgi** module doesn't cause to view to hung on background processes.

I don't know which server do you use, so you can check this behavior with various modules (uwsgi, mod_wsgi, fastcgi) and see what is more suitable for you.
And try to execute in background:

```
subprocess.Popen(["/bin/sleep", "10", "&"])
```

Comment: Especially the command helped, still wondering why the issue occurs

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```py
import subprocess

x = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/sleep", "10"])
x.wait()
```

Comment: This does not help: It blocks the server for 10s.