# Listen EADDRINUSE error while debugging in sails

Tags: node.js, error-handling, terminal, sails.js

I am trying to debug my code using **node-inspector** but I am getting this error in my Terminal window again and again

```
$ sudo sails debug
info: Running app in debug mode...
info: You probably want to install / run node-inspector to help with debugging!
info: https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector

info: ( to exit, type <CTRL>+<C> )

    Error: listen EADDRINUSE
        at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
        at Agent.Server._listen2 (net.js:1156:14)
        at listen (net.js:1182:10)
        at Agent.Server.listen (net.js:1267:5)
        at Object.start (_debugger_agent.js:20:9)
        at startup (node.js:86:9)
        at node.js:814:3
```

To resolve

> Error : listen EADDRINUSE

I have tried closing other Terminal window (in which my node-inspector was running).
I have referred to the [answers already here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898372/nodejs-error-listen-eaddrinuse) but they didn't work 
I have even tried giving this command to kill processes :

```
$ killall -9 node 
No matching processes belonging to you were found
```

but still its not working.
Somebody please help me out with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see that you are using `sudo` so this is not a permissions issue.

It definitely seems like the port is already in use. You should [check to see which process is using the port](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/), then kill that process.

Comment: Thanks @CodeBling 
I am running it on mac and i had tried to kill that individual process which is using the port but that also didn't work.

Comment: @PrernaJain I see that you tried `killall -9` in the question above. Did you try `-9` when killing the individual process, and it still exists? In that case, have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944886/how-to-kill-zombie-process), it's likely a zombie process (note the 'Z' flag).

Comment: Yeah it was actually acting as a zombie process and this was helpful, it works well for me.
Thanks once again @Code

Comment: and yeah, i'll accept your answer now and hopefully my question made it more clear to you, the concepts of 'Z'ombie processes,as it does for me.

Comment: Man! you save my 1 hour of debugging. Thanks

Comment: @JahanzaibAslam Awesome! That's what StackOverflow is for!

Answer (score 4):

There is a [known issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2670) with using `sails debug` on Node v12.0.  There's a [patch](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2670#issuecomment-126420131) which will be released with the next version of Sails (v0.12).

In the meantime you can either [install the edge version of Sails from Github](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails) or apply the patch yourself by replacing your Sails' `/lib/hooks/grunt/index.js` file with the contents of https://raw.githubusercontent.com/balderdashy/sails/88ffc0ed9949f8c74ea390efb5610b0e378fa02c/lib/hooks/grunt/index.js.

Answer (score 1):

First, find your task that uses port 1337:

> netstat -ano | findstr : 1337 (port number)

Then kill it:

> tskill (process ID (PID))

It can solve your problem