# How to Debug my Sails APP with Node-inspector?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I know this question was posted already but I didn't get proper answers.

I installed node-inspector

I typed node-inspector --debug in a console and got this response:

```
        Node Inspector v0.12.3
        Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/?ws=127.0.0.1:8080&port=5858 to start debugging.
```

I got the debugger tool on chrome when go to above url

then from my project folder opened a new console and

ran this command:sails debug

Got these results:

```
info: Running app in debug mode...
info: You probably want to install / run node-inspector to help with           debugging!
info: https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector

info: ( to exit, type <CTRL>+<C> )

 Debugger listening on port 5858

 info: Starting app...

error: Grunt :: Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
     at Agent.Server._listen2 (net.js:1156:14)
    at listen (net.js:1182:10)
     at Agent.Server.listen (net.js:1267:5)
    at Object.start (_debugger_agent.js:20:9)
    at startup (node.js:86:9)
    at node.js:814:3
```

my application running in localhost:1337

But I wonder How debug my app with the tool I got on chrome.

Please Some one help me with this, I need a step by step solution.

Comment: Are you able to get past the EADDRINUSE? I have the identical thing you have and it works fine - I get all the source code, can set breakpoints, etc.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511243/listen-eaddrinuse-error-while-debugging-in-sails/32658328#32658328).

Comment: Thanks for replying.. I cannot edit the /lib/hooks/grunt/index.js