# How to clear GPU memory occupied by zombie process if it's parent is init?

Tags: linux, tensorflow, gpu, init, zombie-process

[nvidia-smi screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aVho.png)

The process with PID 14420 is a zombie process and its parent id is 1(init). I want to clear 4436MiB memory occupied by this zombie process without rebooting.

How should I proceed?

Comment: You should find its parent and kill it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944886/how-to-kill-zombie-process has a good explanation.

Comment: The parent is init, so I think there is no way of killing it without rebooting.

Comment: You could try to lower the initlevel to see if it does anything, but at this point, yeah, perhaps rebooting is the way.

Answer (score 4):

Use this command to list all the processes on the GPU (on Linux).

```
sudo fuser -v /dev/nvidia*
```

and find PID from the listed processes and simply use
`kill <PID>` .

This will kill process with specified ID.