# How to debug when bash hangs?

Tags: bash

How to debug when bash hangs?
I have a script running on an ARM64 linux with bash. It hangs after running for a few hours. pstack shows nothing. strace shows nothing either.
I cannot stop the process even with kill -9.
What else can I do with it to debug?
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the script?

Comment: If you can't kill a process with `kill -9` then it's either stuck in a kernel syscall, which indicates a kernel bug or a hardware problem, or it's a [zombie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944886/how-to-kill-zombie-process): it's exited and its *parent process* hasn't reaped it. If it's the latter forget about the child; you need to investigate the parent.

Comment: How do you know its hanging as opposed to done? Can you re-run it with `bash -x`?

Comment: Do you know what command it's executing (or trying to execute) when it hangs? You can get a trace of what it's executing by putting `set -x` at the beginning of the script (or running it with `bash -x scriptname`). If it runs in the background (or you just don't want the trace filling up your terminal window), you can redirect stderr to a file.