# python subprocess - detach a process

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a python script `af_audit_run.py`, and it calls another python script `request_audit.py` through `subprocess`.

The second script `request_audit.py` invokes another subprocess in the background and returns a request id.

The problem is the first script `af_audit_run.py`, which is supposed to exit soon after the second script returns the request id, is waiting for the entire background process to finish. Is there any way we can force the first script to exit as soon as the request id is returned?

`af_audit_run.py` -- waits for the result using the `communicate` method:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result, error = p.communicate()
print(result.decode('utf-8'))
print(error.decode('utf-8'))
```

`request_audit.py` -- doesn't wait, just detaches a subprocess (3rd python script) and returns request id:

```
subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
print(request_id)
```

environment: Linux

Comment: Please can you show the relevant parts of the existing code.

Comment: @alaniwi, I have updated with the code snippet.

Comment: It works if instead of `stdout=None, stderr=None` you use `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL`. (I'll put some more details in an answer.)

Comment: @alaniwi, This is will redirect the output but doesn't help the first script to come out immediately after it gest return code. I want the first script to not to wait for the 2nd script background process completion.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes I tried . The problem now is capturing the request_id returned by the second script ( not the background ). this is not available in my first script af_run_audit.py", line 51, in <module>
print(result.decode('utf-8'))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode. How do we capture the request_id in the first script? I am sure your solution works to exit without waiting for grand child process ( background process)

Comment: No, you still want `subprocess.PIPE` inside `af_audit_run.py` where you invoke `request_audit.py`. But where the _third_ process is invoked, _that_ is where you want the `subprocess.DEVNULL`.

Comment: See test code at end of my answer. Nothing is changed inside `af_audit_run.py` compared to your version. My change is only inside `request_audit.py`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to ensure that the standard output and standard error of the third process are directed somewhere other than the pipe from which the `af_audit_run.py` is reading output.

What is going wrong with the existing code is that by using `stdout=None, stderr=None`, you are requesting the *default* action (as if you had not used those keywords at all).  This is to write to the same output streams as the parent process, in this case the `request_audit.py`, using the file descriptors which are inherited when the subprocess is forked.  This means that the top-level `af_audit_run.py` will wait for output because it does not see end-of-file on that output stream until the third process has completed.

This can be seen in output of `lsof` - in the following example, the third process is the command `/bin/sleep 600` (see test code at end).

Here is part of the `lsof` output for the third process:

```
sleep   3057  myuser    0u   CHR 136,20      0t0      23 /dev/pts/20
sleep   3057  myuser    1w  FIFO   0,13      0t0 9441062 pipe
sleep   3057  myuser    2w  FIFO   0,13      0t0 9441063 pipe
```

and here is part of the `lsof` output for the top-level `af_audit_run.py`:

```
python3 3053  myuser    0u   CHR 136,20      0t0      23 /dev/pts/20
python3 3053  myuser    1u   CHR 136,20      0t0      23 /dev/pts/20
python3 3053  myuser    2u   CHR 136,20      0t0      23 /dev/pts/20
python3 3053  myuser    3r  FIFO   0,13      0t0 9441062 pipe
python3 3053  myuser    5r  FIFO   0,13      0t0 9441063 pipe
```

As you can see, the `sleep` process in this example (pid 3057) has its stdout (fd 1) and stderr (fd 2) streams connected to write end of the pipes which the top-level process (pid 3053) is reading from -- note the pipe numbers in the second-last column -- even though it is not directly the parent of that process.

You are specifying the `close_fds=True`, but this is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) as follows:

"If *close_fds* is true, all file descriptors **except 0, 1 and 2** will be closed before the child process is executed." *(emphasis mine)*

So it is not having any effect on the stdin, stdout or stderr streams, although any *other* open file descriptors would be closed in the child.

If instead of `stdout=None, stderr=None` you use `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL`, then this will explicitly direct these streams to the null device (`/dev/null` on Linux), and then the `af_audit_run.py` does not have to wait for it.

Some output from `lsof` in this case:

```
sleep   3318  myuser    0u   CHR 136,20      0t0      23 /dev/pts/20
sleep   3318  myuser    1u   CHR    1,3      0t0       6 /dev/null
sleep   3318  myuser    2u   CHR    1,3      0t0       6 /dev/null
```

It is possible also to use `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL` so that if the process tries to read then it will see end-of-file.  In this example I have not done so, and its input is still connected to the terminal device, although this does not affect whether `af_audit_run.py` waits for it.

---

### Test code

`af_audit_run.py`

```
import subprocess

cmd = "python3 request_audit.py"

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result, error = p.communicate()
print(result.decode('utf-8'))
print(error.decode('utf-8'))
```

`request_audit.py`

```
import subprocess

cmd = "/bin/sleep 600"

subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True,
                 stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)

print(5)
```