# spawn xterm shell from python, pass command to it, keep it running if parent process dies

Tags: python, linux

python beginner here! using python 2.7.

my question: from a python process, I want to spawn a new xterm process (and display the gui to the end user) and run a command in it.

NOTE: I know about `process.Popen("xterm")`, however I could not find a way to send the command to xterm, I tried some examples using pipes, but they seem be attached to input/output/error streams.

My end goal is to display a "xterm" gui that shows the progress of another command, also if the parent python process dies, it should not kill the child xterm gui

Comment: Maybe xterm's `-e command` option might be useful.

Comment: This should work : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64145368/2125671