# How to exit out of a Python Script while the script invoked by it still continues to run

Tags: python, subprocess

I have two python scripts out of which one of them does some processing from the data in a excel file. The second script is used to update the data whenever the user updates the excel. After the user modifies the xlsx file he/she can run the second script and it automatically reloads the second script. However the problem here is that since the first script that does the actual processing is having a infinite while loop and when I am executing the file from the second script it doesn't exit after executing the first py file. I just want the second script to execute the first python file once and then exit out while the first script keeps executing infinitely. Here is the code:

```
import notification
import importlib
import subprocess
import os
import sys

importlib.reload(notification)
if os.name == 'nt':
    subprocess.run(["python","notification.py"], capture_output=True)
else:
    subprocess.run(["python3","notification.py"], capture_output=True)
sys.exit(0)
```

Here the name of my first file is notification.py.

Comment: I think you will need to share both your first and second code.

Comment: This is confusing

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `subprocess.Popen` instead of `subprocess.run`

Reference:

[Python spawn off a child subprocess, detach, and exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772873/python-spawn-off-a-child-subprocess-detach-and-exit)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects