# How to spawn a completely detached process in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, process, operating-system

**!!! subprocess** didn't work for me.

I want to run python script `daemon.py` as a daemon. This script needs to be activated from another script called `starter.py`

Requirements:

1. `starter.py` should not wait for `daemon.py` to finish. This requirement is met by using `fork()` in `starter.py`.

```py
import os

pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
   os.system("python daemon.py")
```

This meets the first requirement but still faces a problem, and brings us to the second requirement.

2. `daemon.py` **should keep running even if I quit** `starter.py`. This requirement is not met by using `fork`.

I then tried using `subprocess` as suggested by answers in here [Python spawn off a child subprocess, detach, and exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772873/python-spawn-off-a-child-subprocess-detach-and-exit)

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(['python', 'daemon.py'],
                 cwd="/",
                 stdout=None,
                 stderr=None)
```

This too suffers from the same problem. When I quit `starter.py`, `daemon.py` also stops.
I'm using `SIGTERM` event listener on `daemon.py`. And it is listening to events from `starter.py`. Hence, the problem.

`daemon.py` looks like this.

```py
import sys
import signal

def handler():
    other_business()
    sys.exit(0)

while True:
     business()
     signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler)
     try:
         time.sleep(1)
     except KeyboardInterrupt:
         exit()
```

**PYTHON VERSION**: 3.5.2

How do I run `daemon.py` completely independent of `starter.py`?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using such an ancient Python version?

Comment: The question you linked to has *two* answers, and the second mentions using ``start_new_session=True``. Did you do that?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi , just tried. `start_new_session=True` works, but floods terminal with `stdout`. How can I supress output of new session created ? `stderr` and `stdout` is already set to `None`.

Comment: Send both to dev null via ``subprocess.DEVNULL``.