Subprocess waiting for command to finish, how to let it not wait and still capture the output logs
I am running a python script which runs a shell command.
Aim: To let the command run in background - collecting the logs and the python script performs next step and exits fine without hindering the shell command.
Here are the approaches I tried:
Method 1
command=f"nohup ./run.sh > runLog/nohup.out &"
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)

It waits for the process to finish but that brings my python script on hung state and not able to perform the next steps.

Method 2
command=f"nohup ./run.sh > runLog/nohup.out 2>&1 &"
os.system(command)

It runs the program and exits the script successfully but no log file is generated, which is not what I want.

Can you help me on how to resolve this?
New Approach:
def job_run(command):
    try:
        #os.system(command)
        #subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
        cmds=shlex.split(command)
        p=subprocess.Popen(cmds, start_new_session=True)
        return "Success", f">>> Output of the command: ${command}"
    except Exception as e:
        return "Failure", f"??? An error occured: {e}"

command=f"nohup ./run.sh > runLog/nohup.out &"
        result, output = job_run(command)


Result of this code running:
monitoring]$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'


It does not completely exits, i have to manually hit multiple enters to come out of the script execution.
How can I handle this?

You might be looking for threads. “Python threads” and “Python multiprocessing” are good queries to get started.

Afaik, subprocess.Popen(command) should not wait unless you are using .communicate()

It would be more helpful if you showed all the code that is involved. As it stands we cannot guess what happens after the call to subprocess.Popen. Also since Popen creates a new process by default, you do not need the & character at the end of the command string.

Issue you are encountering might be from os.system as it is not fully detaching the process from the shell.
A better approach would be using the subprocess module, which provides more control over how processes are started and managed.
import subprocess

command = "nohup ./run.sh > runLog/nohup.out 2>&1 &"
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)



The shell is what's hanging around. Popen by itself creates a process which runs in parallel with your Python script, so you really don't need the & background operator.
Here's one way to get rid of the shell:
with open("runLog/nohup.out", "wb") as log:
   process = Popen(["./run.sh"], stdout=log, stderr=log)

You need to eventually call process.wait() for it to be reaped (or process.kill() to kill it). You might also want to look into using communicate() but that's probably not useful for your particular use case.
This skips nohup which requires a shell; but seriously, if you want to run something as a subprocess of your Python script, it should probably not do that anyway.

The command which is running using subproces should run irrespective of python script and should still be in running state after the python script exits. We are running a process which runs for 24hrs or more and this script will hit the program to start.

You can simulate nohup with a simple signal handler. All it really takes is for the process to ignore the HUP signal.

Maybe see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772873/python-spawn-off-a-child-subprocess-detach-and-exit
