# Executing shell commands from a Django app/project

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to be able to execute some shell commands like `mkvirtualenv` and `createdb` and such from a Django app, these processes will likely go into a Django celery task later. I would think using system() would be insecure to execute shell commands from Django/Apache, so my question is what is the best way to execute shell commands from a django app?

Comment: you could use the subprocess module: http://stackoverflow.com/a/546024/630877

Comment: arie, thanks, I will use that. Can you answer below so I can mark your answer?

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer. Happy subprocessing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start a shell process in the background you can use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) module.