# Run Python script from within a 2nd python script in parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scripting

I have script1.py and script2.py...how can I run script1.py and have that automatically execute script2.py in parallel? (I do not want to wait for script2 to finish before continuing on with script1.). Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the [multiprocessing package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/546024/1717828) answer your question?